# How can i extract foreground mask from video and blend it onto background video?

Tags: python, opencv, overlay, masking, blending

I'm working on a basic video summarization project using static camera footage. I performed motion tracking by frame subtraction. Now I want to crop and overlay these objects on the background image such that it appear as if these objects are running simultaneously.

I could not find any resources except for this youtube video which is exactly what i want to do https://youtu.be/gk3qTMlcadk?t=140

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can edit your question to add what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is so broad!

In short, use ‌[background subtraction](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html) methods to separate background image from foregrounds. Then improve the foreground results using [Morphology operations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dbe/tutorial_opening_closing_hats.html). [Track foreground blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12330817/4003077) in video. Merge foregrounds for each blob to create a mask image which shows the blob trajectory (trajectory image). Merge trajectory images with minimum overlap (complex issus!).

Comment: im sorry for not mentioning all the stuff....i used KNN subtractor and then applied different morphological operators and finally used contours to track the blobs. i dont really know how to merge foreground for each blob and thats where im facing pronblem

Comment: Keep all frames of a blob's mask from entrance to exit (remove other blobs in that frames) then [bitwise_or](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab85523db362a4e26ff0c703793a719b4) all of them to create trajectory image.
But as I mention merging trajectories need a heuristic algorithm!